# Polymer starter kit gulp error

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

after downloading and extracting psk1.2.1 and running npm install and bower install, when i run gulp  i get the following output

MacBook-Pro-van-Marco:testb mspro$ gulp

[21:18:46] Using gulpfile ~/www/studies/polymer/testb/gulpfile.js

[21:18:46] Starting 'clean'...

[21:18:46] Finished 'clean' after 5.66 ms

[21:18:46] Starting 'default'...

[21:18:46] Starting 'copy'...

[21:18:46] Starting 'styles'...

[21:18:47] styles all files 98 B

[21:18:47] Finished 'styles' after 559 ms

[21:18:48] copy all files 12.75 MB

[21:18:48] Finished 'copy' after 1.72 s

[21:18:48] Starting 'elements'...

[21:18:48] Finished 'elements' after 3.49 ms

[21:18:48] Starting 'lint'...

[21:18:49] Starting 'images'...

[21:18:49] Starting 'fonts'...

[21:18:49] Starting 'html'...

[21:18:49] Finished 'fonts' after 142 ms

[21:18:51] Finished 'lint' after 2.41 s

[21:18:51] html all files 52.36 kB

[21:18:51] Finished 'html' after 1.35 s

[21:18:51] gulp-imagemin: Minified 6 images (saved 494 B - 1.4%)

[21:18:51] images all files 35.41 kB

[21:18:51] Finished 'images' after 1.64 s

[21:18:51] Starting 'vulcanize'...

ERROR finding /Users/mspro/www/studies/polymer/testb/dist/bower_components/paper-behaviors/paper-button-behavior.html

ERROR finding /Users/mspro/www/studies/polymer/testb/dist/bower_components/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior.html

the paper-behaviors folder was empty (except for the README.md)
i then copied the content of  the bower_components/paper-behaviors folder of the psk-light download and the error was gone, but starting the demo with gulp resulted in an empty page

looking at the console in chrome i get following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.IronMeta is not a function
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
iron-icon.html:168 Uncaught TypeError: this._meta.byKey is not a function
page.js:797 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

here's where i give up for now,

my node version is v4.2.4 on mac osx 10.10.5
Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)

does anyone have a idea how to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: I tried again today on another computer with a fresh download of the same PSK and this time i managed to get it working, still don't know what went wrong, the main difference is the os (the computer with the working version has mac os 10.11.2), node and npm versions are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to include the actual commands you ran and which version of the PSK you tried. Here are the steps I followed and was able to get the PSK installed and run gulp and gulp serve without error.

- Download [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit/releases)
- Under Intermediate - Advanced Users click on polymer-starter-kit-1.2.1.zip
- Extract ZIP file to preferred location
- Install Node.js if needed before running the next step
- With Node.js installed, run the following one liner from the root of your Polymer Starter Kit download:
  `npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install` 
  OR if admin permission is needed: 
  `sudo npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install`
  NOTE: This step takes a few minutes to install all of the dependencies.
- Then start the web server using this one liner from the root of your Polymer Starter Kit download:
  `gulp serve`

Comment: I did all of the steps you mentioned above, the version of the starter kit i used is 1.2.1 as mentioned in my first line